# Checking if two consecutive pairs of coordinates in an arraylist are equal in java

Tags: java, arraylist

The following program should execute 10 times,each time asking the user for a pair of coordinates.I store the x and y coordinates in two separate arraylists.
The program should be able to check if a pair of coordinates has been entered more than once.A message should be printed if that happens.
My program is behaving in a peculiar fashion.Among other things,it seems to print out the message multiple times.

Secondly,say if the user enters a pair of coordinates,I want the program to print out a msg saying 'Wrong pair'.I tried inserting an else statement after the if but that doesn't work.In short,every time a pair is entered,the program should say 'wrong pair',but if a duplicate is entered,it should just say 'already entered'.How would I do that?

```
public static void main(String[]args)
{
    Scanner a=new Scanner(System.in);

    //Arraylist stores all entered x values.
    ArrayList<Integer> XValues=new ArrayList<Integer>();
    //Arraylist stores all entered y values.
    ArrayList<Integer> YValues=new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        int xval;
        int yval;

        System.out.println("Try no. #"+(i+1));
        System.out.print("Please enter x coordinate: ");
        xval=a.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Please enter y coordinate: ");
        yval=a.nextInt();

        if(i>1)
        {
            for(int c=0;c<XValues.size();c++)
            {
                for(int d=0;d<YValues.size();d++)
                {
                    XValues.get(c);
                    YValues.get(d);

                    if(xval==XValues.get(c) && yval==YValues.get(d))
                    {
                        System.out.println("Sorry.Already entered.\n");
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        XValues.add(xval);
        YValues.add(yval);
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the error you got?

Comment: Well,to begin with,the program doesnt print a msg until I've entered about 3 coordinate pairs.Secondly,its printing out the msg multiple times.

Comment: If the user enters a repeat coordinate, do you want to ask them for a new pair until they input one that hasn't been entered yet?  Do you want to store coordinates even if they are duplicates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice your nested `for` loops? The portion where you check your values for previous entries is being run more times than you want it to be run.

For example, when i=3, the user enters their 4th entry, and you are about to check it against the previous 3 entries. Your `for(int d=0;d<YValues.size();d++)` will run three times, but because it is inside the `for(int c=0;c<XValues.size();c++)` loop, that entire loop will run 3 times, for a total of nine times.

Remove the line `for(int c=0;c<XValues.size();c++)`, and the corresponding brackets. In your `if(xval==XValues.get(c) && yval==YValues.get(d))` line, use `get(d)` for both coordinates.

Also, you're checking currently for `i>1`, when you'll actually want to start checking once `i>0`.

The modified code should look as below:

```
public static void main(String[]args)
{
Scanner a=new Scanner(System.in);

//Arraylist stores all entered x values.
ArrayList<Integer> XValues=new ArrayList<Integer>();
//Arraylist stores all entered y values.
ArrayList<Integer> YValues=new ArrayList<Integer>();

for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    int xval;
    int yval;

    System.out.println("Try no. #"+(i+1));
    System.out.print("Please enter x coordinate: ");
    xval=a.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Please enter y coordinate: ");
    yval=a.nextInt();

    if(i>0)
    {

        for(int d=0;d<YValues.size();d++)
        {
            if(xval==XValues.get(d) && yval==YValues.get(d))
            {
                System.out.println("Sorry.Already entered.\n");
                break;
            }
        }

    }

    XValues.add(xval);
    YValues.add(yval);
}
```

}

Comment: I ran the code you edited.The problem still occurs.Say I enter 1,1 4 times.The program prints the msg the 2nd time(which it should),but on the 3rd and 4rth time,the msg is printed more than once.That's what the problem is.The rest works perfectly fine.

Comment: Gotcha. Check out the edited code now, added a break after the message. Do you see why it helps?

Comment: Would appreciate if you accepted my answer, if it works!

Comment: what's not working? can you post your code with the else statement?